# How to build a re-usable component for React Navigation's Tab.Screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, dry

Learning React Navigation 6 I'm taking an old Tab Navigator and upgrading it with an emphasis on D.R.Y principles:

old tab navigatior:

```js
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={tabOptions}>
  <Tab.Screen
    name={routes.HOME}
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 20,
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome5
            name="home"
            size={20}
            color={focused ? colors.red : colors.grey}
          ></FontAwesome5>
        </View>
      ),
    }}
    listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
      tabPress: e => {
        Animated.spring(tabOffsetValue, {
          toValue: 0,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start()
      },
    })}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name={routes.SEARCH}
    component={SearchScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 20,
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome5
            name="search"
            size={20}
            color={focused ? colors.red : colors.grey}
          ></FontAwesome5>
        </View>
      ),
    }}
    listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
      tabPress: e => {
        Animated.spring(tabOffsetValue, {
          toValue: getWidth(),
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start()
      },
    })}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

since I'm repeating the `options` and I am not using any icons other than Font Awesome I tried building a component:

```js
const TabScreen = ({ name, component, icon }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Screen
      name={name}
      component={component}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <View style={styles.tabBar}>
            <FontAwesome5
              name={icon}
              size={20}
              color={focused ? colors.red : colors.gray}
            ></FontAwesome5>
          </View>
        ),
      }}
      listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        tabPress: e => {
          Animated.spring(tabOffsetValue, {
            toValue: 0,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start()
        },
      })}
    />
  )
}
```

but my error in the terminal is:

```
Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'TabScreen' for the screen 'Home'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.
```

So I built an icon function just for the `options`:

tabScreenIcon.js:

```js
const tabScreenIcon = name => {
  return {
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <View style={styles.icon}>
        <FontAwesome5 name={name} size={20} color={focused ? colors.red : colors.grey} />
      </View>
    ),
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
  },
})
```

app.js:

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.HOME}
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={tabScreenIcon('home')}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      Animated.spring(tabOffsetValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start()
    },
  })}
/>
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.SEARCH}
  component={SearchScreen}
  options={tabScreenIcon('search')}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      Animated.spring(tabOffsetValue, {
        toValue: getWidth(),
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start()
    },
  })}
/>
```

Now I'm trying to get my animations to work which currently do not and my Tab Screens are still not D.R.Y. Is there a way to build a reusable `Tab.Screen` that I can just pass the props `name`, `component` and animation value?

Answer (score -1):

Navigators have `screenListeners` and `screenOptions` props which apply to all screens. You don't need to repeat them.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options#screenoptions-prop-on-the-navigator
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#screenlisteners-prop-on-the-navigator

Comment: If that is the case how else is the Animated Spring supposed to fire?